# Responding to a query for a grant to attend conference

Tags: application, funding

I applied for a grant to attend a conference last month and received the following query:

> We are currently in the middle of assessing the Conference Attendance
>   applications and the assessors would like to ask you for a further
>   explanation on how XXX research is related to
>   and brings benefits to, the Internet? Is it expected that XXX will
>   bring connectivity to an isolated individual?

Now, I am thinking about how to respond to them. My concerns are,

(i) Should I respond them back simply in the form of email (the way I received their query) or should I make a .pdf document for it?

(ii) Should my answer be very detailed or just to the point (in which case, it may be one short paragraph only)?

(iii) Any other do's and dont's !

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I respond them back simply in the form of email?

Yes, it is far easier to process.

> Should my answer be very detailed or just to the point?

Either, but if it is detailed, then structure is key: Reply in a manner that the reader can stop reading as soon as they are satisfied. This likely requires you to open with a single paragraph summary (possibly concluding with "Further details are provided below, should you be interested" or similar).

> Any other do's and dont's !

If *XXX will bring connectivity to an isolated individual*, then the application of your research is seemingly narrower than the organisers would like. Otherwise, make sure to explain how XXX brings connectivity to more than an isolated individual.